# Telegram Bot: Get Chat Title

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to get the title of a group chat but it always pass me `Undefined array key "chat"`
This is the code I'm using:

```
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$title = $update['chat']['title'];
```

I'm probably doing something wrong with the bot APIs, this is the result of /getChat?chat_id=`telegram_id`

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"id":TELEGRAM_ID,"title":"NAME","type":"supergroup",...}}
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$title = $update['chat']['title'];
$chatid = $update['message']['chat']['id'];
if ($chatType == 'supergroup'){
     sendMessage($chatid, "The chat is: $title")
}

function sendMessage($chatid, $text){
    $url = "api.telegram.org/botBOT_TOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=$chatid&parse_mode=HTML&text=" . urlencode($text);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Comment: Check the content of `$update`, if that key is missing. We don't know how you populated it or what it's supposed to contain, so there's not much else we can say

Comment: I edited the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: There is no `chat` key in the results you show.  Maybe modify your question and show more of the result. Those `...` are what, your way of saying there's more?

Comment: But in the [Telegram APIs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) `title` is under `chat`

Comment: chat `title` you can only get if your bot was launched in supergroups, channels and group chats

Comment: Yeah, I'm only executing in a supergroup, as shown in the results of /getChat

Comment: @Seba Oh, didn't notice. Then add your complete json to the question

Comment: Show us a [mre] of the issue, please

Comment: I just added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: `this is the result of /getChat?chat_id=telegram_id` ...it's not clear, how does that result relate to the PHP code you show afterwards. You're getting `$result` from `php://input` which is basically the incoming data of the request to PHP. What are you sending to your PHP? Do `var_dump($result);` and show us what it contains.